# Add data to one table based on matching variable of the second smaller table

Tags: r

I need help in solving this problem. I have two tables. They are of different lengths. I want to add code information to the second table based on ID match with the first.

```
year <- c(2018,2019,2020,2021)

ID <- c("001","002","003","004")

code <- c("AA", "DD", "CR", "RT")

d1 <- data.frame(year, ID, code)
```

```
> d1
  year  ID code
1 2018 001   AA
2 2019 002   DD
3 2020 003   CR
4 2021 004   RT
```

```
d2 <- data.frame(year = c(2017, 2018,2019,2020,2021),
  ID = c("012","007","011","003" ,"004"),
  code = NA)
```

```
> d2
  year   ID code
1 2017  012 <NA>
2 2018  007 <NA>
3 2019  011 <NA>
4 2020  003 <NA>
5 2021  004 <NA>
```

It should go like this.

```
d2
  year   ID code
1 2017  012 <NA>
2 2018  007 <NA>
3 2019  011 <NA>
4 2020  003  CR
5 2021  004  RT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NA` created is `NA_logical_` by default.  It should be the same class as the as the column 'code' in 'd1' - character.  So, either create the columns as `NA_character_` or convert to character class with `as.character` and then do a join

```
library(data.table)
d2$code <- as.character(d2$code)
setDT(d2)[d1, code := i.code, on = .(ID)]
```

-output

```
> d2
   year  ID code
1: 2017 012 <NA>
2: 2018 007 <NA>
3: 2019 011 <NA>
4: 2020 003   CR
5: 2021 004   RT
```

#### data

```
d2 <- structure(list(year = 2017:2021, ID = c("012", "007", "011", 
"003", "004"), code = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Only I also needed to add by=.EACHI

Comment: @AlexandrKorenkov the `.EACHI` is needed only if you are going to do some summarisation of other columns and update though

Comment: this is the error I got.  

Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: @AlexandrKorenkov that would be an issue only if there are duplicates for the key to use cartesian join. In the example, i didn't find duplicates for the column

Comment: akrun I got it, thanks. I used different data in the example to show the problem. My working dataframe has the same problem, just the observations there are under 200k.